# Print at client side using hosted application

Tags: javascript, applet, client-server

I have a hosted application (http://xyx:8080/myapp), Now hosted application is holding a lot of documents.

The requirement is like to print these documents from app only (providing a print button, on click of print the printing job(using java API + Apache pdfbox)will be sent to default printer configured in the system).

Now the real problem whenever client/s click on print it is printing at the hosted computer's default printer.

Now I need to make these document to print at the client/s default printer.

Gone through a lot of websites, couldn't find anything relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If at your client, they are just using a browser.   You have no control of the printer..

Comment: @Keith, Tell me what are the options we have.

Comment: What some company's do is ask them to install a little bit of software at the clients end, to act as a proxy for the printing.  But it's not a trivial task, but it can be done.   One option to make your life easier, -> https://www.printnode.com/

Comment: @Keith, Oh no it is commercial, our company doesn't allow to use the third party softwares

Comment: Well unless you make your own alternative, the best I can think of -. `window.print()`, this goes to the default printer, the user will still need to action it though,.  Using media queries the current page can be reformatted for print.

Comment: @SuryaprakashPisay did you find any solution for this? Currently having issues with chrome browser using window.print. It worked perfectly with IE. Chrome doesn't support javascript to be run on the client m/c.

Comment: @Bab, No, I left the firm.